# Mongoose Model.find() methods query string not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, mongoose

im trying to make simple rest api. I have a collection in mongodb and i connected my db to my app with mongoose pkg. I can access all items without query strings with `Operator.find()` but it doesn't work with query string ex: `Operator.find({name:'Kapkan'})` it returns all of them. Also `Operator.findOne({name:'Azami'})` doesn't work either. The query string returns the first element of the collection no matter what.

```
app.get('/api/operators',async(req,res) => {
  let operators;
  try{
    if(req.query.name){
      Operator.find({name:'Kapkan'}).then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
      });
    }
    else
      operators = await Operator.find();
  
    res.send(operators)
  }catch(er){
    console.log(er);
  }
})
```

Comment: Can't see much on the first look. I am assuming you have hardcoded "Kapkan", for representation purpose, however If not
```
Operator.find({name:req.query.name}).then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
      });
    }
```
shouldn't it be this.

Plus also can you show a sample of Operator Schema.

Comment: I checked schema and i realize what i forget. Thanks mate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked my Schema and i realize i forgotten put name field...

```
const OperatorSchema = new Schema({
    _id:Number,
    logo:String,
    image:String,
    unit:String,
    *name:String,
    side:String,
.
.
.
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not assigning result of query with filter to operators. Unsure if you have `{}` around else or not but try refactoring the code as shown below:

```
app.get('/api/operators',async(req,res) => {
  const filters = {};

  if (req.query.name) {
    filters.name = req.query.name; 
  }

  const data = await Operator.find(filters);

  console.log(data);

  return res.json({ data });
})
```